# How to capture the name of sub folder from directory path in powershell

Tags: powershell

My script is running in a loop on files and display the path for each file, I need to capture the name of the lower sub folder above the file name or even 2 subfolders (maybe there is a way to capture the needed subfolder or something)

For example:

```
$file = C:\Users\Bandit\AppData\Local\Temp\9c86ee608bb9477ebb11914c36a5a76d\638110173610123239\IDUDatabase_4.0.0.119\IDUDatabase\test.sql
```

Currently I know to remove a prefix and to display the relevant path (without the temp and sub temp)

```
$displayPath = ($file.FullName).Substring($subTemp.Length + 1)
$displayPath
# IDUDatabase_4.0.0.119/IDUDatabase
```

**But** its not what I need!!

I want to get the lower subfolder above the file name . in this case I want to get  the 'IDUDatabase' (or if it possible to get also the IDUDatabase_4.0.0.119)

Example 2:

```
C:\Users\Bandit\AppData\Local\Temp\9c86ee608bb9477ebb11914c36a5a76d\638110173610123239\ElcServices_4.0.0.120\ForwarderServiceVersion_8_6x\test.dll
```

The output should be 'ForwarderServiceVersion_8_6x'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### cmdlet version

This way uses pure PowerShell cmdlets...

```
$path = "C:\Users\Bandit\AppData\Local\Temp\9c86ee608bb9477ebb11914c36a5a76d\638110173610123239\ElcServices_4.0.0.120\ForwarderServiceVersion_8_6x\test.dll"

# get the full path of the parent directory
$parent = Split-Path -Path $path -Parent;
# "C:\Users\Bandit\AppData\Local\Temp\9c86ee608bb9477ebb11914c36a5a76d\638110173610123239\ElcServices_4.0.0.120\ForwarderServiceVersion_8_6x

# get the last part of the above
$name = Split-Path -Path $parent -Leaf;
# ForwarderServiceVersion_8_6x
```

You can put this together into one expression as follows:

```
$name = Split-Path -Path (Split-Path -Path $path -Parent) -Leaf;
# ForwarderServiceVersion_8_6x
```

and you can simplify that a bit more by leaving out optional / default parameters:

```
$name = Split-Path (Split-Path $path) -Leaf;
# ForwarderServiceVersion_8_6x
```

### dotnet version

Alternatively, if you don't mind a bit of dotnet class interaction you can do this:

```
$name = $path.Split([System.IO.Path]::DirectorySeparatorChar)[-2];
# ForwarderServiceVersion_8_6x
```

which splits the full path into an array of components and then returns the second-to-last item.

**Update**

If you want to select arbitrary parts of the path you can use the dotnet version and extract the directory levels that you're interested in as follows:

```
$separator = [System.IO.Path]::DirectorySeparatorChar;

# get the last two directories in the path
$name = $path.Split($separator)[-3..-2] -join $separator;
# ElcServices_4.0.0.120\ForwarderServiceVersion_8_6x

# get the last two directories and filename
$name = $path.Split($separator)[-3..-1] -join $separator;
# ElcServices_4.0.0.120\ForwarderServiceVersion_8_6x\test.dll

# get everything except the first $x parts of the path
$x = 7;
$parts = $path.Split($separator);
$name = $parts[$x..($parts.Length-1)] -join $separator;
# 638110173610123239\ElcServices_4.0.0.120\ForwarderServiceVersion_8_6x\test.dll
```

Comment: Thank you @mclayton. I modified the question because I want to know if there a way to go up. Assumed that this will not work $name = (Split-Path (Split-Path $path) -Leaf ) -parent
I want to get each time the upper subfolder (starting from the lower as you write)

Comment: @Bandit - I've added an update. If you need something more specific you might need to give literal examples in your question...

Comment: Very helpful 
$name = $path.Split([System.IO.Path]::DirectorySeparatorChar)[-2];

Comment: Hi @mclayton
There is a command to know how many parents/levels the file has?